# why js files works on localhost but not working on ftp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ftp, localhost

The links are connected correctly on ftp but not executed.

There are no UpperCases on file names like -> "jQuers.js " and 
I tried online libraries like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` but it's also not working.

my template link -> http://uidev.eu5.org/work/newtimes_rtl/

Comment: lots of errors that jquery isn't defined - you need to load jquery (as per the script tag in your question) probably before bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put jQuery before everything that is dependent on it first in the `<head>`.

Ideally though you should move all your script tags to your footer - but still have jQuery first.

[image]

Comment: thanks , i do it but still the same problem scripts not excuted !

Comment: most of the console errors are now gone (about 50 of them). There are 2 console errors left. You should hold shift while you refresh the page or clear your cookies. Crtl + shift + delete.